# AS3 - NativeMenu affecting Button components

Tags: actionscript-3, button, air, native

In my AIR application, I use Flash's `Button` component for most of my simple buttons. But for some reason, when I give the window a `NativeMenu`, the buttons look a bit different. Specifically, the text appears to be smaller.

Here's what I mean. Without the `NativeMenu`:

[image]

The button appears normal. But when I add a menu bar:

[image]

As you can see the button looks different. In fact, now that I look at it again, the `TextArea` seems a bit smaller too.

If anyone knows why this is happening and how to prevent it that would be great.

Comment: Make sure the `Y` value of the two components are on whole numbers like 100 and not 99.4, for example.

Comment: Yep, they're both on 50.

Comment: Agree with Ronnie, it looks more like yours components are blury because anti-aliased than smaller. Try to set them in absolute integer coordinates (maybe by figurinh out what is the native bar height).

Comment: Strange. When I put both the `x` and `y` values at 0, I still get the same effect. However, the component actually appears at a slightly different location to when I remove the menu. A `y` of 0 is directly below the menu, with a pixel or two downwards, but the `x` is 10 or so pixels to the right of the actual edge of the window. But when I remove the menu, the coordinates (0, 0) are exactly in the top-left corner. You're probably right about anti-aliasing, but I'll see if I can find out any more about this placement.

Comment: So figured it out: see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `NativeMenu` is scaling down the stage, resulting in the smaller, blurry components. This can be avoided by changing the stage's `scaleMode` property:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```